# Ubuntu webapps - Caching/preload/offline ability?

Tags: webapps

Is there any provision for Ubuntu [Webapps](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/web/) (that is HTML5 websites packaged as apps) to cache/preload any data or pages ?

Using a hypothetical Twitter Webapp on a Ubuntu Phone as an example:
Would I be able to open twitter on my commute and continue to look at individual tweets as I go through tunnels ?
If I navigated elsewhere within and returned sometime later to Twitter, would it cache/store or would it need to reload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web apps on Ubuntu Touch support the offline app cache standard (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#offline), however this needs to be handled by the application author (in your example Twitter, who haven't implemented this yet). As far as I'm aware there isn't currently any other facility for implementing caching without the co-operation of the webapp owner.